# How to create global model in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I need to create global model(class) in Angular 2.

That I can retrive properties and set them any time.

I tried:

```
export class GlobalModel {

  private a: number;
  private s: number;

  constructor(s: number, a: number) {

  }
}
```

But in each component I need to initialize model `new GlobalModel()`, that resets previos statement.

Comment: you mean sharing data across components?

Comment: Yes, it should be available in each  component, also it should be editable

Comment: you should use shared services or redux store technique

Comment: Just put @Injectable() on it and add the class to the AppModule providers section.

Comment: Then to use set/get?

Comment: Do you mean add to AppModule as provider?

Comment: Create a service that instantiates this model class, and have getters and setters in the service to operate on the object instantiated earlier.

Comment: Can you share an example, it is hard to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrying forward with the example @Aman mentioned in the comment.

Something like this will do the job

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Test {

  public _test:any;

  constructor(_test: any) {

   }

  set test(value:any) {
    this._test = value
  }

  get test():any {
    return this._test;
  }
}
```

Add this to the providers array of app module like `providers: [ TestService ]`

You can also go down the redux route for redux using ngrx take a look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)