# Angular dependency injection and destructuring object constructor

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Assume a simple class "Model" defined as below. The Model class has `Injectable` decorator to `provideIn: "root"` for global model use case. I also defined arbitrary constructor for this class using destructuring signature, because I want to define certain local instances from Model if needed? But angular DI system throws the following error:

> No suitable injection token for parameter '0' of class 'Model'.
> Consider adding a type to the parameter or use the @Inject decorator
> to specify an injection token.

How to provide the model class correctly?

```
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class Model {
  param1: string;
  param2: string;
  constructor({ param1 = "", param2 = "" } = {} ) { 
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
  }
}
```

One solution is the `useFactory` option in the providers array and  create Model entity manually, e.g.:

app.module.ts

```
...
providers: [
  { provide: Model, useFactory: () => (new Model({param1:"test"})) }  
]...
```

And the decorator `@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root' })` in class Model has to be removed, when using factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ready to only provide your class with `useFactory`, just remove `@Injectable()`

Only use `@Injectable()` if you want the constructor parameters to be provided automatically by the dependency injection.

The alternative is you using an `InjectionToken` but that doesn't seem to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for notice to remove the decorator. I edited my post, because I tried the example with `@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root' }) ` before I came through factory approach and run into same error.

Comment: Yes, the parameters of your constructor need to be injectable when you use `@Injectable()`.

Comment: Can you please show how to create injectable parameter using the Model class example.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what you want. A model should be injectable contrary to a service

Comment: I was thinking about a global class entity to manage certain data or, let's say, a global Model using MVC terminology. My first thought was to provide the model entity like a global service entity. And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907714/how-to-create-global-model-in-angular-2) has confirmed my opinion. There for I used injectable decorator and run into issue as described. Then I go for the factory approach. But if I got you it's possible to use the decorator as well, but how?

Comment: Don't use the constructor to set the data if you want to use `@Injectable()`